# python for loop when using file instead of dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am using my own file instead of a Python dictionary, but when I am applying a `for` loop on that file I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

My code is given below where "sai.json" is the file that contains the dictionary.

```
import json
from naiveBayesClassifier import tokenizer
from naiveBayesClassifier.trainer import Trainer
from naiveBayesClassifier.classifier import Classifier

nTrainer = Trainer(tokenizer)

ofile = open("sai.json","r")

dataset=ofile.read()
print dataset

for n in dataset:
    nTrainer.train(n['text'], n['category'])

nClassifier = Classifier(nTrainer.data, tokenizer)

unknownInstance = "Even if I eat too much, is not it possible to lose some weight"

classification = nClassifier.classify(unknownInstance)
print classification
```

Comment: `n` is a string,  not a dictionary.  Please do a bit of research on how to parse json. Use the `json` module

Answer (score 1):

You are importing the `json` module, but you aren't using it!

You can use [json.load](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) to load JSON data from an open file into a Python `dict`, or you can read the file into a string and then use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads) to load the data into a `dict`.

Eg,

```
ofile = open("sai.json","r")
data = json.load(ofile)
ofile.close()
```

Or even better

```
with open("sai.json", "r") as ifile:
    data = json.load(ofile)
```

Or, using `json.loads`:

```
with open("sai.json", "r") as ifile:
    dataset=ofile.read()
data = json.loads(dataset)
```

And then you can access the contents of `data` with `data['text']` and
`data['category']`, assuming the dictionary has those keys.

You're getting an error because `dataset` is a string so

```
for n in dataset:
    nTrainer.train(n['text'], n['category'])
```

loops over that string character by character, putting each character into a one element string. Strings can only be indexed by integers, not other strings, but there's not much point indexing into a one element string, since if `s` is a one element string then `s[0]` has the same contents as `s`

---

Here's the data that you put in the comment. I was assuming that your data was a list wrapped in a dict, but it's ok to have a plain list as a JSON object.
FWIW, I used `print json.dumps(dataset, indent=4)` to format it. Note that there is no comma following the last `}` in the file: that's ok in Python, but it's an error in JSON.

**sai.json**

```javascript
[
    {
        "category": "NO", 
        "text": "hello everyone"
    }, 
    {
        "category": "YES", 
        "text": "dont use words like jerk"
    }, 
    {
        "category": "NO", 
        "text": "what the hell."
    }, 
    {
        "category": "yes", 
        "text": "you jerk"
    }
]
```

And now if we read it in with `json.load` your code should work correctly. But here's a simple demo that just prints the contents:

```python
with open("sai.json", "r") as f:
    dataset = json.load(f)

for n in dataset:
    print "text: '%s', category: '%s'" % (n['text'], n['category'])
```

**output**

```
text: 'hello everyone', category: 'NO'
text: 'dont use words like jerk', category: 'YES'
text: 'what the hell.', category: 'NO'
text: 'you jerk', category: 'yes'
```

Comment: I m still getting an error "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"  .how can i change n from string to an integer in this for loop.

Comment: I am getting an error in this for loop :-                                                       for n in dataset:
  nTrainer.train(n['text'], n['category'])

Comment: @Neha: That code looks exactly like the code in your question. But maybe you misunderstand what I said before. That code is **incorrect**. Did you try using one of the three methods I showed of reading your "sai.json" file into a Python dictionary? If that file doesn't contain valid JSON dat then the `json` module will give an error message when it tries to load it. Once you have it loaded then the proper way to access the data fields you need depends on the structure of the JSON data. Maybe you should post a sample of your data into the question.

Comment: @Neha: BTW, changing `n` from a string to an integer would only give you a different error message. The Python interpreter's not complaining because `n` is a string, it's complaining because `'text'` is a string. `n['text']` is the correct syntax for accessing the `'text'` field from a dictionary named `n`. But your `n` isn't a `dict`.

Comment: This is the actual code i want to implement and this is giving the write output but the problem is that i want to store those four lines of "dataset" in a file and than use or load  this file to run the code

Comment: nTrainer = Trainer(tokenizer)
dataSet =[
    {'text': 'hello everyone', 'category': 'NO'},
    {'text': 'dont use words like jerk', 'category': 'YES'},
    {'text': 'what the hell.', 'category': 'NO'},
    {'text': 'you jerk','category': 'yes'},    
]
for n in dataSet:
    nTrainer.train(n['text'], n['category'])
    
nClassifier = Classifier(nTrainer.data, tokenizer)
unknownInstance = "Even if I eat too much, is not it possible to lose some weight"
classification = nClassifier.classify(unknownInstance)
print classification

Comment: @Neha If my answer has helped you, please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.